# Why do some posts appear faded out?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know why some posts like this [one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/are-wcydwt-questions-on-topic/2685#2685) appear faded out.

Answer (score 16):

Answers that have a score of -3 or below are shown greyed out, to de-emphasize them.